# How to point ApiGateway to a specific Lambda alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a resource in Amazon's ApiGateway.  It is pointing to a Lambda function.  This is being hit by a native mobile application (android and ios) which is already in the wild.

I now want to modify the Lambda function, but I see no way to change my ApiGateway resource to point to an alias of the lambda.  This is my first time playing with any of these technologies and I see no easy mechanism to manage this in the aws console.

**How can I modify my ApiGateway resource to point to my lambda alias so I can edit trunk without affecting existing clients?**

Comment: Refer [How to use API Gateway stage variables to call specific Lambda alias?](https://youtu.be/mwD5wiP1FJ8)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Under Integration Type -> Lambda Function you need to add a reference to the stage variable `MyLambdaFuntionName:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` and then for each stage set the `lambdaAlias` in the Stage Variables tab accordingly(lambdaAlias=dev, lambdaAlias=prod, etc.)

There is an example with screenshots here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

Its kind of hidden towards the very bottom of the page starting with "Alternatively, you can mix and match static names"

Comment: Note that when specifying a Lambda function name as a stage variable value, you must configure the permissions on the Lambda function manually. See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll have a look at it this weekend and accept this answer when I get it going.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, If I do it with just `MyLambdaFunctionName` it works, but get 500 error if i do `MyLambdaFuntionName:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}`

Comment: Hi @Ray , don't forget to give the API method permission, just input `yourlambda:DEV` ... and the rest envs , apply them one by one,  and finally you cloud just apply`yourlambda:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}`

Comment: If you have many lambda functions, you can use 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/59426777/4160530' script to speed up the 'add permission' process.

Comment: How can I achieve this using CloudFormation considering I am using AWS::Serverless::Function to create the lambda ?

Comment: I tried this for an HTTP API on API Gateway and the solution worked. In the new UI you just need to add this directly on the ARN name as opposed to adding it on a separate input area.

Answer (score 8):

For the later googler, be careful to add permissions WITH the correct alias like yourfunc:prod not only yourfunc. That means if you'r planning to use 3 alias to invoke the lambda functions, you have to add 3 of them.

Comment: The great thing is the policy sticks with the alias so as you point the alias to other versions of the lambda function, it'll just work.

Answer (score 6):

On the Api Gateway console, use ARN instead of a lambda function name.

Comment: This was the simplest solution for me... Publish a version of the Lambda function with a name like "prod" and then copy/paste it's ARN into the API Gateway's Integration value. Done.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I would add directly the arn of the lambda function to replace the Lambda name. This works for me without have to to add the {} notation.