# How do you point API Gateway to a lambda Alias in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Using CDK to connect ApiGateway to a lambda, we first create a RestApi(), and then create a LambdaIntegration to connect the Apigateway to a lambda. How do you do this when working with a lambda Alias?

[How to point ApiGateway to a specific Lambda alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472724/how-to-point-apigateway-to-a-specific-lambda-alias) explains how to connect ApiG to a Lambda alias without CDK. How can this be translated to CDK?

Our goal is to add provisioned concurrency and autoscaling to a lambda used with API Gateway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`LambdaIntegration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaIntegration.html) Function gets [`handler: IFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.IFunction.html) as a parameter  which is the lambda object.

With that been said, you can import the lambda version you want using the following code snippet:

```js
const lambdaAlias=lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(scope,'LambdaImportUsingARN',"lambdaAliasARN")
```

Replace `lambdaAliasARN` with the ARN of your lambda.

e.g -

```
arn:aws:lambda:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT}:function:${LAMBDA_NAME}:${ALIAS_NAME}
```

And later, pass it to `LambdaIntegration` :

```js
const lambdaIntegrationUsingAlias  = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdaAlias)
```

In addition, the lambda alias needs permissions in order to allow the ApiGateway to invoke it.

```kotlin
const lambda = ...
const alias = Alias(this, "alias-id", AliasProps.builder()
            .provisionedConcurrentExecutions(1)
            .version(lambda.currentVersion)
            .aliasName(ALIAS_NAME)
            .build()
        )
// First add permission for your stage to invoke
alias.addPermission("apigateway-permission", Permission.builder()
            .action("lambda:InvokeFunction")
            .principal(ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com"))          
            .sourceArn("arn:aws:execute-api:$region:$account:${api.restApiId}/$stage/POST/$path")
            .build())
// Next add permission for testing
alias.addPermission("apigateway-test-permission", Permission.builder()
            .action("lambda:InvokeFunction")
            .principal(ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com"))
            .sourceArn("arn:aws:execute-api:$region:$account:${api.restApiId}/test-invoke-stage/POST/$path")
            .build())
```

Comment: This is not correct - the lambda returned by `Function.fromFunctionArn()` will always point to `LATEST`, even if you specify an alias name. You need to import an `Alias` explicitly.

Comment: @gshpychka could be that the CDK team update the logic. When I posted this answer - it worked. hence, the upvotes.

Comment: Or maybe the upvoters didn't realize that they're still pointing to the latest version.

Comment: I have used it by myself, so it's not possible.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a TypeScript CDK example of an "API Gateway HTTP API" backed by a Lambda using an alias and autoscaled provisioned concurrency.

See [autoscaling docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html#autoscaling) for more info.

```js
import * as apigateway from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2'
import * as apigatewayIntegrations from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations'
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda'

const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
  //...
})

const liveAlias = new lambda.Alias(this, 'LiveAlias', {
  aliasName: 'live',
  version: fn.currentVersion,
})

const target = liveAlias.addAutoScaling({
  minCapacity: 1,
  maxCapacity: 100,
})

target.scaleOnUtilization({
  utilizationTarget: 0.75,
})

const httpApi = new apigateway.HttpApi(this, 'HttpApi', {
  defaultIntegration: new apigatewayIntegrations.LambdaProxyIntegration({
    handler: liveAlias,
  }),
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This also works for setting the gateway to point to a Java lambda version with alias with the new SnapStart feature.