# api gateway can not find the lambda alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

for HTTP API Gateway, with Lambda integration, how to set integration target to be a Lambda function alias?

From console, when I input the lambda alias arn, it shows that  `No matching lambda functions` error.

I am pretty sure that ARN and AWS Region is right.

[image]

Edit:
This is HTTP api gateway.  `$` is not allowed.
[image]

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472724/how-to-point-apigateway-to-a-specific-lambda-alias

Comment: Hey it is different. My api gateway is HTTP API Gateway.

Comment: @xiaokang-lin Did you work this out?

Comment: Are you able to find this?

Answer (score 0):

Try copy the arn from within your lambda, to avoid any typos